# Can an admin validate sign-up requests in Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there something similar to the [email verifcation](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-app-email-settings/) feature where a system admin could validate user sign-up/registration requests?

**Background:** We're building a system with a closed community, where new users can join only if an admin has verified their sing-up data.
Ideally the admin should just receive an email that there's a new registration request and validate the request directly from the email.

Answer (score 0):

The `emailVerified` column is protected - it can only be updated by the system in response to the target user clicking the link in the validation email.

An admin can not "tick" this field on behalf of another user.

However.  From your brief description of the background I would suggest that you want the users to click the link - after all it serves to validate their email address.  If you are creating your own app there is nothing to stop you adding your own column to the user model (or preferably a related table) and implement code in your sign up that also checks this extra column.  Of course this is more work - but likely not excessive - and you get the desired workflow.